# Find basis of subset. Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

Can someone help me and with this problem (sorry for not finding the correct "R" and P2 should be P underscore 2)

Let $P2=\{a0 + a1x + a2x^2$
| $a0, a1 ,a2 \in R \} $

And  $S=\{p(x) \in P2 | p(1)=0\}$

**QUESTION:**  *Find a basis B of S*

And this is my solution

$p(x)= a+bx+cx^2$

$p(1)=0=a+b+c=0$  therefore $a=-b -c$

so $p(x)=-b-c+bx+cx^2$

$p(x) = b(-1+x) +c(-1+x^2)$

the basis should be $(-1+x)$  ,  $(-1+x^2)$

is this correct? if its not, where am i doing wrong?

the answer according to the answer sheet is $(-1+x),(-x+x^2)$ and i dont understand how they got that basis.

Comment: You just posed the question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3552378/help-me-solve-this-linear-algebra-problem-find-a-basis-of-the-set). Please don't post questions multiple times. Also see the comments there and try to improve your posts.

Comment: Please don't repost a question that has just been closed.  That said, vector spaces can have more than one basis.

Comment: Okay im really sorry, i thought i deleted the old comment :( and i dont understand whats wrong with the question now

Comment: "whats wrong with the question now"? Here is the comment by Paul you deleted with the old question:"What do you mean by help? Where are you stuck? What part of the problem don't you understand? Do you know what a subspace is? Do you know what a basis is? Do you know what is meant by "extend"? How can anyone help you if they don't know your specific problem? "

Comment: okay thanks for the feedback. I will try to do better in future...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $p(x)=-x+x^2$ and $q(x)=-1+x$, then $p,q \in S.$

Furthermore: $\{p,q\}$ is linearly independent, thus $\dim S \ge 2.$ since $S$ is a proper subspace of $P_2$, $ \dim S \le 2.$ Thus $\dim S=2$ and $\{p,q\}$ is a Basis of $S$.

Your basis is also correct.

A basis of a vector space is not unique !

Comment: Okay thank you very much!